# Homescreen appears to be on while it's off

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-4, home-screen

I know it sounds weird, but when I turn off the screen using the power button I have the feeling that it doesn't turn off completely.

I'll try to explain why.

- I press the power button, the home-screen fades off and screen goes black. This is normal
- I press the power button again, the screen is turned on and home-screen fades in. This is normal too, but it doesn't not always happen. Sometimes the home-screen appears immediately without the animation then fades off! It's like the screen is turning off again. I have to press the power button again to turn it on.

Does anybody know what could cause this issue? It only started to happen recently, I think after I updated some apps, but I don't know which. Perhaps someone is having the same problem and was able to track down the app? Could it be Nova launcher?

I'm using Android 4.4.4 on rooted Nexus 4. I tried Android 5.0 - 5.1.1 but I had bigger problems with it, like randomly going into deep sleep every day or apps crashing and forcing system restart.